# How to convert a numerical string into an int array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

Suppose I have a string "12345" but want to make it into an array, what code or function allows me to do that?

Example:
I input: "12345" and I want it to turn into the array (same as typing) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in c++. I know that the function stoi.("12345") converts the string into an integer, but how would I go about making that integer be an array?

Comment: That's what you want. What have you *tried*?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, to further clarify, do you want the "array" to be an array of characters or of integers?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "int array", as per the title

Comment: Characters are integers. OK. I'm being overly pedantic. I need to stop that. It doesn't help.

Comment: And as I feel nice, here's a couple of hints: If you have a `std::string` containing the number, then you can loop over it. The first character will be the `'1'` (in your example). And you can easily convert a character from a character to its corresponding numeric equivalent of the digit by simply subtracting the character `'0'`. I.e. `'1' - '0' == 1`

Comment: I've tried converting the string into an integer using the stoi.() function, and I'm contemplating on somehow looping through each integer and copying each them into an array, but I just don't know if there's a function or if I'm approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: I want it to be an array of integers

Comment: Iterating over the digits of an integer is hard. If you have a string then iterating over the "digits" (really characters) of the string is much easier. And as mentioned in my previous comment, you can easily convert a digit in a character to its corresponding "integer" value.

Comment: Look at the duplicate @frslm dug up. Quite likely by googling string to int array. Lot of gold in them thar googles.

Comment: yeah thanks guys, I've had a long day so excuse the dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write such function:

```
std::vector<int> toIntArray(const std::string& str) {
    const std::size_t n = str.length();

    std::vector<int> digits(n);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        digits[i] = str[i] - '0';  // converting character to digit

    return digits;
}
```

Or if you cannot use `std::vector`:

```
void toIntArray(int* digits, const char* str) {
    while (*str) {
        *digits++ = *str++ - '0';
    }
}
```

But you have to be confident array size is enough to store all digits.

Comment: Or use the built in functions. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9fdbe001e9d0df4

Comment: I can only use <iostream>, <fstream>, and <string>.

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to explain this to me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidZhu If you have no more questions, mark my answer as accepted, please.

Comment: @boriaz50 there